# HTML Form Validation Popup using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

I am trying to add a popup when any fields in a form I am creating is empty after clicking submit. The popup works fine when I click submit but when I click the reset button or once all fields have been entered, I want the popup to disappear which is not working. Please note I can only solve this using Javascript(or Jquery) and CSS, and the **HTML code cannot change**.

Javascript (I have included here what I think is relevant):

```
function showPopUp(){

  popUp = document.createElement( "div" );
  popText = document.createElement( "p" );
  popUp.id = "popUp";
  document.body.appendChild( popUp );


  popText.id = "popText";

  popText.innerHTML = "Still have fields empty";
  popText.style.marginLeft = popUp.width / 2 + "px";
  popText.style.marginTop = popUp.height / 2 + "px";
  document.body.appendChild( popText );


  return false;
}
function closePopUp() {
    popText.parentNode.removeChild(popText);
    popUp.parentNode.removeChild(popUp);
}
```

showPopUp(); runs in the checkContactForm( this ) function.

HTML:

```
<form id="contact" action="" onsubmit="checkContactForm( this ); return false;" >
<p>
  <label for="name">First name:</label>
  <input name="name" id="name" onfocus="resetField( this );" />
</p>
  <label for="message">Your Message:</label>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" onfocus="resetField( this );"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
  <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset Form</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have close popup function called when you click reset button. For example:

With Jquery!

```
$("button:eq(1)").click(function(){
    closePopUp();
});
```

Or with javascript, you can add onclick function on your html

```
onclick=closePopup()
```

For checking all the input fields, you can use each function

```
$("input").each(function() {
   var element = $(this);
 if (element.val() == "") {
   isValid = false;
 } 

  });
```

Comment: With the javascript way, how would I identify the reset button given my HTML above?

Comment: <button type="reset" onClick = "closePopUp()">Reset Form</button>

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this code could work. You would be getting `popText is undefined` and `popUp is undefined` in the console.

To rectify that change your closePopUp() to somewhat this:

```
function closePopUp() {
    popText = document.getElementById('popText');
    popText.parentNode.removeChild(popText);
    popUp = document.getElementById('popUp');
    popUp.parentNode.removeChild(popUp);
}
```

If you have some other issue display on console please share that.

Better still if you can create a fidde on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)